# Converting foreach to for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have a script that removes from array if the length is greater than 6.

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) 
{
    if (strlen($value) > 6) 
    {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

which I convert to for loop:

```
for($i=0, $j=0 ; $i<count($array) ; $i++)
{
    if(strlen($array[$i])<6)
    {
        $lessthan6[$j] = $array[$i];
        $j = $j+1;
    }
}
```

which is not unset the array it just stored to a new variable of array.

what is the equivalent of `foreach($values as #value => $val)` in `for loop`? i'm quite confused. thanks for helping me in advanced.

Comment: in for loop you used `<6` not `>6`!

Comment: Can you explain better your question? What you want to do?

Comment: @Caffè what is the equivalent of `foreach($values as $value => $val)` in for loop?

Comment: @noizer i need the foreach statement converted to for loop

Comment: @Destiny for($i=0; $i<count($array) ; $i++) ??

Comment: You either do a `foreach` loop or you do a `for` loop. They're not equivalent. If they were equivalent there'd be no need for two different constructs. What do you really want to know?!

Comment: @noizer read carefully my question

Comment: @deceze i want the 1st code converted to for loop.

Comment: Looks like you already did it. What's the problem with your `for` loop?

Comment: @deceze the for loop I made stored the filtered to a new variables i want it to be unset like the 1st code

Comment: Also: `$lessThan6 = array_filter($array, function ($str) { return strlen($str) < 6; });`

Comment: Uhm... `unset($array[$i])`?!

Comment: can you make some examples :( without using a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0, $length = count($array); $i < $length; $i++) {
    if (strlen($array[$i]) > 6) {
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: im getting errors undifiend offset

Comment: I don't: http://3v4l.org/1AH3A

Answer (score 0):

```
$keys = array_keys($values);
for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
    $key = $key[$i];
    $value = $values[$key];
}
```

You should probably check out array_slice() which will make your task, if I understood correctly, a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array("Prashant", "Ghimire" , "is" , "a", "good", "boy");
for($i=0, $j=0 ; $i<count($array) ; $i++)
{
    if(strlen($array[$i]) <= 6)
    {
       unset($array[$i]);
    }
}
var_dump($array);
?>
```

Comment: @peashant is there any way to unset it not to put it on the new variable?

Comment: use var_dump($array); at last

Answer (score 0):

Read the array in reverse order:

```
for($i=count($array) - 1; $i>= 0 ; $i--)
{
    if(strlen($array[$i]) > 6)
    {
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
}
```